# writeLines() does not completely work inside a for loop

Tags: r, ampl

I have a for loop, in which I print the results in a .txt file. However, the writeLines() works only for a certain number of iterations. Furthermore, I got the following warnings when executing my code: closing unused connections.

```
Script <- function(solver=NULL, modelDirectory="/home/fernandafalves/Desktop/Tese/") {
library(rAMPL)
ampl <- new(AMPL)

if (!is.null(solver)) {
    ampl$setOption("solver", solver)
}

ampl$read(paste(modelDirectory, "/Data_Simheuristic_CaseII.txt", sep=""))

for(scenario in 1:1){
    for(value in 1:1){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        for(variation in 1:3){
            fileConn <- file("ResultSimheuristic_CaseII.txt", "a")

            ...

            for(mm in 1:M){
                for(l in 1:CARD[[mm]]){
                    Mean <- Expected_OF_BS[l,mm]                        
                    SD <- Standard_Deviation[l,mm]
                    Min <- Minimum[l,mm]
                    Max <- Maximum[l,mm]
                    prob <- signif(1 - pnorm(112,Mean,SD), digits = 3)

                    writeLines(c(paste("Machine:", mm), paste("Sequence Number:", l), paste("Mean:", Mean), paste("SD:", SD), paste("Minimum value:", Min), paste("Maximum value:", Max), paste("Probability:", prob), "\n"), fileConn)                             
                }   
            }
            close(fileConn)     
        }
    }
}
```

}

In the .txt file in the last iteration of the for loop, it prints only until the line paste("Minimum value:", Min).

Answer (score 0):

I have read a while ago about strange behavior with `writeLines()`. Here is the [R-bloggers Article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-mysterious-case-of-the-misbehaving-writelines-or-a-cat-saves-the-day/).
I think you could use the [write](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/write.html) function with `append = TRUE` argument.

```
write(line, file = "filename", append=TRUE)
```

Comment: The write function resulted in the same problem. Not all the lines are printed in the .txt file.